# Pass a complex Object to Angular Directvie

Tags: angular, angular-material

i'm trying to pass a complex object to my directive (and that is a different formFontrol so i can't use [formControl], formControlName etx...)

```
<input matInput appDateInputEvents [control]="fieldGroup.get('date')">
```

that is my directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDateEventsInput]',
  standalone: true,
  
})
export class DateInputEventsDirective {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() control!: AbstractControl;

  //MORE STUFF

  }
```

but angular dosen't reconize [control] as a know property
instead if i use just control witout square brackets angular reconize it as property but just as String

so what i shoud do?

Comment: Your directive's selector is "appDate**Events**Input", but in your `<input>` element you are using "appDateInput**Events**". Both are different. Are you sure your directive works?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try to pass a getter to your directive to ensure the template is correctly interpreting what you're trying to do.

**in your ts file**

```
public get dateFormControl(): FormControl { 
       return this.fieldGroup.get('date'); 
}
```

**in the template**

```
<input matInput appDateInputEvents [control]="dateFormControl">
```

Answer (score 0):

And remember: if you're using Modules, add in "declarations" the DateInputEventsDirective , if you're using standalone components add in "imports" the DateInputEventsDirective.

BTW, if you use

```
@Input('appDateEventsInput') control!:AbstractControl
```

And you can write

```
  <input matInput [appDateEventsInput]="fieldGroup.get('date')">
```

NOTE:Another thing you can do, as you aplied your directive in a input that mannage (or not) a FormControl (or a [(ngModel)]) you can get it inject in constructor the NgControl

```
control!:AbstractControl
constructor(@Optional() ngControl:NgControl)
{
   if (ngControl)
      this.control=ngControl.control;
}
```